# How can you shift a Defined Name using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a rolling calendar spreadsheet that tracks various metrics. The script I would like to write would shift the selected range in a named each time it is ran.

I did have success incrementing the spark lines using this macro:

```
If Sheet2.Range("E5").SparklineGroups.Count > 0 Then
    With Sheet2.Range("E5").SparklineGroups.Item(1)
        .SourceData = "'" & Range(.SourceData).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(.SourceData).Offset(, 1).Address
    End With
End If
```

However, I am stuck referencing the defined name `Hzrange` using a similar macro below. I am very new to VBA and any help is appreciated as always.

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Names("Hzrange").RefersToR1C1 > 0 Then
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Hzrange")
        .RefersToR1C1 = "'" & Range(.RefersToR1C1).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(.RefersToR1C1).Offset(, 1).Address
    End With
End If
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  what error do you get or what problem results from running it?

Comment: `Names("BLAH").RefersToRange.Offset(1, 0).Name = "BLAH"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Names("Hzrange").RefersToR1C1 > 0 Then
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Hzrange")
        .RefersToR1C1 = Range("Hzrange").Offset(, 1)
    End With
End If
```